# Sails.js - Load Balancer Health Check - Ignore Session

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

I am using Sails.js for an app. The app is behind a Load Balancer. Every time the Load Balancer performs a health check on my server (http://SERVER_IP/healthcheck), Sails.js saves a session record to the database. This makes my database have way more records that it supposed to have.

Is there any way to have Sails.js ignore sessions when the Load Balancer hits my server?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sails `session.js` configuration provides an option `routesDisabled` that allows you to specify routes that you would like to bypass the session middleware. This is important in production situations where you're persisting session data in a data-store and each 30-second ping from a health check or external API call that doesn't rely on session authentication ends up creating a new entry that may not expire for 30 days.

Ex:

```
routesDisabled: ['GET /health/check']
```

[Link to documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session)